# Importing quizzes into Canvas with supplement file

Tags: r-exams

I don't seem to be able to correctly import an exam generated with this [lm](https://www.r-exams.org/templates/lm/) template.

The `exams2canvas("lm.Rmd", n = 10)` function will generate the following error:

> Error in switch(type, num = "numerical_question", schoice = "multiple_choice_question",  :
> EXPR must be a length 1 vector

I can export it with `exams2qti21`, but then Canvas will not offer the supplemental file (without generating any import error). This is the HTML of the question

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Using the data provided in <a>regression.csv</a> estimate a linear regression of <code>y</code> on <code>x</code> and answer the following questions.</p>
<p><br /><br />b. Estimated slope with respect to <code>x</code>:<br /><br /><br /></p>
```

As you can see no href...

Comment: I assume this is about `exams2canvas()` not `exams2tcexam()` as previously shown in the question. Then I suspect the problem is that cloze exercises are not supported in `exams2canvas()`, yet, which is not caught correctly leading to the rather opaque error message. Could you try to use a `num` or `schoice` or `mchoice` question instead to see whether supplements work with that?

Comment: Yes, with `num` works. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback. I've fixed the error message in the development package and added an answer here on SO (so that it can be officially flagged as resolved). It contains some additional background in case you or anyone else is interested.

Comment: Would you consider accepting my answer below so that the question is officially flagged as resolved? That would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

This is not about the supplementary files but about the question type. Using supplementary files with a single question (num, schoice, mchoice) works correctly in `exams2canvas()`.

**Background**

The error in `exams2canvas()` is caused by the "cloze" question with schoice and num elements. Canvas supports only cloze questions with schoice elements placed in the text (displayed as multiple dropdowns). Hence, the question cannot be prepared for Canvas correctly.

Clearly, the error message was not helpful in pointing to this problem. In the devel version of the package I have now added an explicit error message for this.

The problems with the `exams2qti21()` output are probably due to insufficient customizations for Canvas. Internally, `exams2canvas()` interfaces `exams2qti12()` (QTI 1.2 not 2.1) but with several tweaks so that the resulting output can be imported correctly into Canvas. For the output from `exams2qti21()` we have not been able to do similar tweaks to make it work correctly.

The problem with the missing supplements is most likely caused by the default `base64 = TRUE` in `exams2qti21()`. Base64 encoding is not supported in Canvas and such content is simply stripped upon import, hence the missing href.